# How can make a downloader for flutter chat app, and just download files once

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i develop a chat application powered by flutter. it will able to download multiple file type, some times big files. it need to download once it save in local. next time read form local storage.
help to solve this.
its better to use no package.

Comment: Where do you need help?

Comment: first,i need help, for download every type of file, then check if exist dont let app to download it again. and finally open it by default apps.

Comment: The type of a file is irrelevant at download. So where would you need that download help?

Comment: i need configuration for ios and android. in app download, dont stop it when navigate to other screens, if return to the screen countinu showing progress. and when it complete open it by default app. just once download not very time clicked download.

Comment: Nice design. There are a lot of specific steps to program.  Please choose one step. Post the code for that. Tell the troubles you have with that code. Then ask a to the point question.